# Getting position right in css closer to centre?

Tags: html, css

Hihi, I'm making a coming soon site for my upcoming game and I have been struggling with this for hours! http://endlessreturn.com/ is the site and basically, is there anyway I can get "Check out the trailer" bit closer to the actual trailer?

```
    IMG.logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }

IMG.copyright {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }

.center
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:100%;
display: block;
background-image:url('/images/trailer.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;

background-position:right; 
}

img.floatLeft { 
    float: left; 
    margin: 4px; 
}

body
{
background-image:url('/images/bg.gif');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}


#wrapper {
    width: 467px;
    margin: 29px auto;
    }
#logo {
    height: 397px;
    text-indent: -10000px;
    margin-bottom: -135px;
    }

#form {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 25px auto 15px auto;
    }
form {
    background: url(/images/newsletter.png) no-repeat;
    height: 90px;
    }
input {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
}
input.text {
    width: 400px;
    height: 75px;
    padding: 0px 0px 30px 90px;
    color: #505050;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    }
input.submit {
    width: 165px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 50px 0 13px 10px;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    }.center iframe {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
}



<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Endless Return - 2D MMORPG</title>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="style.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
</head>
<body>

<IMG class="logo" src="/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
<div class="center">
<center><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2IMOh6JAJkY" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>

</div>
</div>
<IMG class="copyright" src="/images/copyright.png" alt="logo">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You image and you `CSS` need to be adjusted.

You need to have the image a bit larger, allowing it to be centered as background of the current `div` and have the arrow and text beside the video.

**See this example with an image of 1280px:**
[image]

*This example uses an image wide enough in relation to the video width.*

**UPDATED CSS:**

```
.center {
    background-image: url("/images/trailer.png")
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**And the link** [to the image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76169930/stackoverflow/question/10711104/trailer.png) with 1280px of `width`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of right center, use x% y%
The first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the vertical. The top left corner is 0% 0%. The right bottom corner is 100% 100%. If you only specify one value, the other value will be 50%. . Default value is: 0% 0%